# Add extra data to a simple_form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using the simple_form gem.

I'm rendering an input based on a collection (a list of all my `actiontypes`)

```
<%= f.association :actiontype, collection: Actiontype.all, input_html: { data: {'impacts-pnl' => ??}} %>
```

I would like to be able to add a data-attribute to the input to store extra data.

In this case, I want to store the `impacts_pnl`attribute of my `actiontype`. The only problem is that I don't know how to refer to the current `actiontype`

`collection.impacts_pnl` doesn't work (obviously)

`actiontype.impacts_pnl`neither.

how can I pass this extra bit of data to my input?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to add these attributes to the option-elements of a selectfield, you should alter the collection by using for example the .map() function. Also, use the input helper with block to do this, otherwise it doesn't work;

```
= f.input :actiontype do
    = f.select :actiontype, Actiontype.all.map{|a| [a.name, a.id, {"data-impacts-pnl" => p.impacts_pnl}]}
```

For more information about this issue, see https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/188

Comment: thanks, I had missed the part where you need to specify the `f.select` as part of a block!

Comment: And how do I had a class to the `<select>` and not to child `<option>` elements?